Adding extra parameters to the inputs of a network?
I have a bunch of images of cells from a brightfield microscope that I want to segment. Cells have different morphologies, shapes, etc. depending on cell lines. I also have some metadata associated with each image (i.e. the cell types and some other qualitative information). My question is, would including that data along with the images provide a strong signal to guide the network during training, or is it better to just let the network train on images alone? Thanks ahead of time.
